# Dockerfile is not installing packages

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, dockerfile

Im trying to build an image and getting the following error

```
 docker build -t flask_objectdetection  .
[+] Building 1.8s (7/12)
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 362B                                                                               0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:18.04                                                    1.5s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                  0.1s
 => => transferring context: 288.50kB                                                                              0.1s
 => [1/8] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu:18.04@sha256:8aa9c2798215f99544d1ce7439ea9c3a6dfd82de607da1cec3a8a2fae005  0.0s
 => CACHED [2/8] RUN apt-get update -y                                                                             0.0s
 => ERROR [3/8] RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev libgl1-mesa-glx      0.3s
------
 > [3/8] RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev libgl1-mesa-glx:
#0 0.258 Reading package lists...
#0 0.267 Building dependency tree...
#0 0.267 Reading state information...
#0 0.268 E: Unable to locate package python3-pip
#0 0.268 E: Unable to locate package python3-dev
#0 0.268 E: Unable to locate package libsm6
#0 0.268 E: Unable to locate package libxext6
#0 0.268 E: Unable to locate package libxrender-dev
#0 0.268 E: Unable to locate package libgl1-mesa-glx
------
Dockerfile:3
--------------------
   1 |     FROM ubuntu:18.04
   2 |     RUN apt-get update -y
   3 | >>> RUN apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev libgl1-mesa-glx
   4 |     WORKDIR /code
   5 |     COPY . /code
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c apt-get install -y python3-pip python3-dev libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev libgl1-mesa-glx" did not complete successfully: exit code: 100
```

I have tried pulling the packages FROM python as well with no luck. I have checked the ports and my cluster can be accessed both internal and external with no issues.

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. When I build an image with the first 3 lines of your Dockerfile, it builds as it should.

Comment: Are you in some kind of restricted network? Behind a firewall or similar?

Comment: It can be important to `RUN apt-get update && apt-get install` in a single command.  I don't think you're hitting the symptom of the wrong thing happening (HTTP "not found" errors on packages that have been updated since the last rebuild) but that could be one thing to try.

Comment: I tried RUN apt-get update && apt-get install in a single line but still the same problem

Comment: LinFelix@ ports are working fine, I can ping internally and externally. Im not sure if this has something to do with DNS

Comment: You can try this solution, maybe it will help https://askubuntu.com/questions/839202/dpkg-error-processing-package-libgl1-mesa-glxi386-configure